# The smallest dot product

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, vectors, sums-of-squares

Consider an $n$-dimensional vector $V$ $(C_1 ,C_2 , . .. ,C_n)$ such that $C_i$ 
is a Whole number.
Is it possible to find a vector such that the dot product with itself is a perfect square ?
*If possible   find such vector* , *provided $ n  $.*

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clear that the $C_i$ are strictly positive. The term "natural number" is ambiguous. Incredible, but true $-$ see for instance [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).

Comment: By the way, I think your question would be better without the artificial requirement that $C_i<10$.

Comment: Think $\pmod{3}$

Comment: @Empy2 - I don't understand your hint of mod 3.  Do you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: Starting from all 1s, replacing one 1 at a time by 2 will  increase the sum by 3s, quickly reaching a square unless n is 2 mod 3

Comment: Your solution for 11 adds to 49, but 11111111223 adds to 25

Comment: Why did you undo my edit? ["Whole number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) is even worse that "natural number"! Oh well, I'm not going to edit it again.

Comment: Originally the problem involved finding a vector "of minimal magnitude", which language is omitted in the current version.  It is important to note that the OP apparently wishes to exclude zero from the entries, something @TonyK earlier sought to clarify.  The existing Answer by Dietrich Burde shows how all interpretations might be solved, but it would have been preferable to have edits by the OP that cleared up which interpretation was intended.

Answer (score 3):

Every positive integer (and hence also every square) is the sum of $4$ squares.
This is [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem). Thus we have
$$
m^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2.
$$

Note: the edited question asks for a solution of
$$
m^2=x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2,
$$
where $1\le x_i\le 9$ are integers. In other words, given $n\ge 1$, find a sum with $n$ terms with each term in $\{1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81\}$, which gives a square.

Example: $n=5$. Then a solution is $1^2+1^2+1^2+2^2+3^2=4^2$.
I suppose this has always a solution for every $n$. For the "minimal magnitude" one could think that one should use many summands $1^2$, but this is not clear. This could be a difficult problem.

Comment: That theorem and its proofs still blow my mind.

Comment: You can always add more squares $0^2$. In general, you cannot with less than  $4$ squares.

Comment: It is not clear to me that for the minimal magnitude, one should use as many $1^2$ as possible.  What if this forces your last few squares to be bigger?  Maybe I'm missing some obvious logic...